# Type mismatch on basic "apply twice" hello world in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, visual-studio-code, first-class-functions

The minimal code:

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice f = f . f

main = do
   return twice ++ "H"
```

The errors generated:

```
stack runhaskell "c:\Users\FruitfulApproach\Desktop\Haskell\test.hs"

C:\Users\FruitfulApproach\Desktop\Haskell\test.hs:5:1: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `IO t0'
                  with actual type `[(a0 -> a0) -> a0 -> a0]'
    * In the expression: main
      When checking the type of the IO action `main'
  |
5 | main = do
  | ^

C:\Users\FruitfulApproach\Desktop\Haskell\test.hs:6:20: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Char' with `(a -> a) -> a -> a'
      Expected type: [(a -> a) -> a -> a]
        Actual type: [Char]
    * In the second argument of `(++)', namely `"H"'
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: return twice ++ "H"
      In the expression: do return twice ++ "H"
    * Relevant bindings include
        main :: [(a -> a) -> a -> a]
          (bound at C:\Users\FruitfulApproach\Desktop\Haskell\test.hs:5:1)
  |
6 |    return twice ++ "H"
  |                    ^^^
```

How would I logically fix this issue myself?  Clearly it's something I'm doing wrong.  Am I missing a preamble that every example should have?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? The fundamental problem is that `twice ++ "H"` is trying to append a string to a function, which doesn't really make any sense at all. I suspect you might have meant `twice (++ "H")` which is applying the function `twice` to a function. That would "work" in that it would compile, but then you would have a `main` of type `IO (String -> String)` which doesn't really make much sense either. (It would certainly have no observable effect when ran.) Do you want to just define a function `g = twice (++ "H")` and play around with it? If so, just do that.

Comment: @RobinZigmond the general problem is.  I'm looking at examples from: http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions and they're not working at least not as explicitly written.

Comment: Thank you for the link (I have been through LYAH several times, although not for a while - it was my entry point into Haskell - and I dind't recognise this example). It looks like you're trying to experiment with the function called `applyTwice` in that chapter. Yet your attempt looks nothing like the examples in the book, so I advise you to look closer at those (for one thing, in those examples there is no `main` in sight - as far as I remember most examples in LYAH are designed to be ran in GHCi after loading the appropriate function definitions from a file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As RobinZigmond mentions in the comments, you can’t write `twice ++ "H"`. This means, ‘take the function `twice`, and append the string `"H"` to it’. This is clearly impossible, since `++` can only append strings and lists together. I suspect that what you meant was `twice (++ "H")`. This takes the function `(++ "H")`, which appends `"H"` to the end of its argument, and runs it twice.

But even if you do this, there is still a problem. Take a look at the program which is created if you do this:

```hs
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice f = f . f

main = do
   return (twice (++ "H"))
```

Even though this program compiles, it doesn’t do anything! You have set `twice (++ "H"))` as the return value of `main`, but the return value of `main` is always ignored. In order to produce output, you need to use `putStrLn` instead of `return`:

```hs
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice f = f . f

main = do
   putStrLn (twice (++ "H"))
```

But this program doesn’t work either! `twice (++ "H")` is a function, which cannot be printed. This function must be applied to a value in order to produce a result:

```hs
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice f = f . f

main = do
   putStrLn (twice (++ "H") "Starting value")
```

This program should finally work, giving an output of `Starting valueHH` when it is run.